# Duplicate dialog close button causes preview to be too narrow

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog

The close button on the close/flag dialogs causes the form inside to be narrower than intended. This happens on all views, but it's particularly noticeable when voting to close as duplicate because it causes the duplicate preview pane to be too narrow and scroll horizontally.

The following screenshot illustrates the problem:

[image: form forced to be too narrow]

This is caused by the overflow setting on the form:

```
#popup-close-question #close-question-form {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

...in conjunction with the close button being floated right.

I'm not positive on what the best solution is, but removing the overflow if possible is one option, as is changing the way the close button is positioned:

```
.popup-close {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: My name's on there! I feel famous!

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of crazy that this ancient design bug has apparently never been fixed — especially since, as far as I can tell, basically all it takes is one simple line of CSS:

```css
.popup-close { margin-left: -100% }
```

(Note: I have not tested this fix to see whether it might have unwanted side effects in other parts of the UI where the `popup-close` class name might be used, if any.  If that *is* an issue, the selector can be modified to make it only apply to the closing dialog.)

Of course, properly tidying up the UI also requires fixing any other bits of CSS that implicitly assume the existence of this bug, such as the hardcoded pixel width (or, rather, the *multiple* different hardcoded widths!) of the dupe link entry box below.  A quick test with the Chrome dev tools suggests that something like the following CSS should do the trick:

```css
.popup #search-text, .popup .close-as-duplicate-pane .actual-edit-overlay {
    width: 100% !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Using `.popup-close { margin-left: -100% }` currently breaks the ability to use the close button to close the popup for reviewing a suggested edit on a question page. While I didn't look all that much at alternate solutions, changing the CSS to `#popup-close-question .popup-close { margin-left: -100% }` was sufficient to resolve the issue and retain the fix for the duplicate list in the close-vote dialog.