# Dupehammer: don't just automatically close a question, give the Wielder a choice of whether to use Great Power

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, dupehammer

I just voted to [close a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281423/append-the-code-numbers-line-for-java-util-logging-logger?noredirect=1) as a duplicate. There were previously no other votes to close. After I voted to close, the question was closed. This puzzled me for a second, and then I realized it was the Most Foul Dupehammer at work again, because I have a gold `java` badge.

**Could you please make use of the Dupehammer an option rather than an automatic process?**

I do not like the Dupehammer, either being on the receiving end or on the causing end, and given the option to close without additional votes, I would not choose to do so.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges (asking if such thing already exists; It doesn't exist) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer which asks to make it clear you have the hammer, before you actually use it.

Comment: If you aren't sure the question should be closed, then don't vote to close. Hammer or otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree with you on that one. I prefer consensus. But you're right about this question being a duplicate.