# Gold badge holder(s) in "Discussion" closing/opening post(s) on meta as duplicate

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, dupehammer

I have just seen a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335524/do-we-require-people-with-gender-pronoun-preferences-to-be-nice-too) closed as a duplicate by someone who has the dupe hammer powers due to having a gold badge in the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.   This hits me as an unintended outcome, as no one can be a subject matter expert in discussions on meta (we don't use the tag for questions about discussion.....)

Maybe the dupe hammer should just be disabled on meta, as it will take coding time to disable it for only one tag.

---

I don't consider the person misused their powers as a reasonable case can be made that the question is a duplicate, but it was not a clear cut duplicate.

Comment: MSO dupe for this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363066/veteran-users-should-not-get-to-unilaterally-dupe-hammer-meta-contributions

Comment: Tempting to use my dupe hammer here ... just to invoke an unintended outcome ...

Comment: @TadeuszKopec not a 100% dupe. I didn't hammer that question the OP used as an example, it was Servy this time ...

Comment: Yep I protested against the same thing back then and it got down-voted into meta hell for some reason. Since then I've too gotten a discussion gold badge, so now I'm also one of the  "Masters of Discussion", fear my wrath. _Justify those posts that died, by wearing a badge, we're the chosen-..._

Comment: (we don't use the tag for questions about discussion.....) It's a meta-tag identifying what kind of post the question is (discussion, bug, feature-request, or support). I don't see the problem with someone who has 1000+ score over 200+ answers being given the same power to identify "this topic has been discussed before" as one would for a technical topic like a programming language.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I disagree; while I'm hesitant to use one of my dupehammers in the current situation around the Code of Conduct changes, it's **very** useful to handle the umpteenth variation of "Please require a comment before downvoting" or "I can't ask questions anymore, what do I do now?". Those questions are often mistagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) (they're actually [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions), and if I correct the tags I can't use the dupehammer anymore.

The current situation is hopefully only temporary, there's no need to change the rules right now. You can [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/295232) the gold tag badge holder with a comment to ask them to reconsider this particular closure.

Comment: Shame there is not a way for someone with the dupe hammer to cast a normal close vote, when they choose.

Comment: @IanRingrose There's a [feature request for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276047/dupehammer-dont-just-automatically-close-a-question-give-the-wielder-a-choice)... Ironically, it was closed as a duplicate using a dupehammer.

Comment: @Ian - Moreover, from what I've seen, when a newly-minted dupe-hammer is wielded for the first time, it often catches the person casting the vote by surprise, because they thought they _were_ casting a normal close vote.